# Replace Encrypted RAID Card

Tags: security, raid, hp-smart-array, risk-management

Im completely inexperienced in this topic, therefore excuse me if my question is redundant.

We are thinking about deploying Servers with HP Smart Array P840 Controller and using the HPE Secure Encryption for security.
The HPE Secure Encryption is, according to its QuickSpecs, a Smart Array controller based encryption solution which creates, stores and deletes the keys automatically by the Smart Array Controller.

My question, for which I couldnt find any information online: In the event of a controller hardware failure, will it be possible to recover the encrypted RAID by simply replacing the controller and providing some kind of recovery key or will it be required to restore it via a backup?

Answer (score 1):

You can either keep the codes somewhere central yourself or use their own centralised key management software - it may even be free if I recall correctly.